# Selecting a specific element in CSS

Tags: html, css

Sorry about the very generic post title. But what I'm after here is this:

```
<div id="my-div">
   <span>
      <a href="#">link 1</a>
      <a href="#">link 2</a>
   </span>
   <a href="#">link 3</a>
</div>
```

How would I select 'link 3' in CSS? Without editing that Html there **at all**. This is the html that presented with and I need to select link 3 without selecting link 1 and 2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you posted literally means "Find any `a` that are inside of `div#my-div` and are the direct child of their parent."

Use

```
div#my-div > a
```

Using the `>` changes the description to: "Find any `a` that are the direct descendents of `div#my-div`" which is what you want.

Comment: Ah I see, I was wondering what that ' > ' symbol meant. Thank you very much.

Comment: you can use selectoracle (http://tux.theopalgroup.com/cgi-bin/css3explainer/selectoracle.py) to understand the exact translation of any css rule.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following CSS selector:

```
div>a
```

or

```
#my-div>a
```

This will select any `a` that is a direct descendant of a div, or the element with ID "my-div" (whichever is most appropriate to you).

E.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        div>a 
        {
            color:Red;
        }

        #my-div>a 
        {
            color:Blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="my-div">
   <span>
      <a href="#">link 1</a>
      <a href="#">link 2</a>
   </span>
   <a href="#">link 3 (this will be blue as per CSS)</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
#my-div > a {
    color:red
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XJm7D/)**

This Symbol target elements which are direct children of a parent element.

Check the more information **[here](http://userinterfacehome.blogspot.in/2012/11/css-selectors.html)**

Comment: Wow very nice. I've never seen that before, what is the purpose of the ' > '. What does it do exactly?

Comment: @Relborg > symbol target elements which are direct children of a parent element.

Comment: It selects the `childs` not `grandChilds`.

Comment: Brilliant, do you get ' < ' also? if you do, what does THAT do?

Comment: @Relborg Go through this link http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Comment: @Relborg it is expected parent selector.

Answer (score 1):

```
#my-div>a{
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#my-div span + a {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

In this specific case I would suggest the use of an adjacent selector. Using a direct child selector ">" also works but you create the potential pitfall that if another link (i.e. link #4) was added directly after it, that link would also inherit those styles. The adjacent selector ensures that ONLY link #3 is selected even if more elements are added later on.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy with Adjacent sibling selectors in CSS.

In your case you can select link 3 by using,

```
#my-div + a + a {
/* your CSS Rule */
}
```

More info can be obtained from w3c [**adjacent-selectors**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)