# iterating specific elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know in jQuery you can iterate through all elements of a specific type with:

```
$(function() {
   $('img').each(function() {
   });
});
```

what if I want to itterate through elements in a specific div, I tried using the `('#div' > a)` selector but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: please post your markup so we can suggest a suitable selector for your needs

Comment: Your selector should be  `'#div > a'`, not  `('#div' > a)`

Comment: what do you want..?? please be clear in question...even you are doing wrong in question it must be `$('div > a')` which is called parent child selector in `jQuery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
$(function() {
      $('#div_id img').each(function() {
           alert($(this).attr('src'));
      });
});
```

Comment: `img` tag does not have `href` attribute,

Comment: @Gautam3164 Works perfect, whats the difference between this selector and the one I used ? Isn't the > for children ?

Comment: yes `>` means `direct child` while `#div img` means all the image inside `#div`.

Comment: @Crossman http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085688/selecting-a-specific-element-in-css/15085787#15085787  this answer make it clear

Comment: see the edit....you need to specify that div using its id or class,then the selector wont go any conflict

Answer (score 0):

> "what if I want to itterate through elements in a specific div, I
>   tried using the ('#div' > a) selector but that doesn't seem to work"

It's `$('#div > a')`, and this will only target `a` elements that are direct children of the element with `id` `div`.

To iterate over these you can do the following:

```
$('#div > a').each(function (index) {
    console.log(this); //your a element
    console.log(index); //the loop index
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you have shown: Your css style selector should indeed be $("div > a") (citing dystroy) if only if the a-tag is an immediate descendant (i.e. child) of a div-tag otherwise I'd rather go for $("div a") which will search all descendants.

Note i've removed #div from here - I'm assuming you really mean a reference to a div-tag and not some element with the id 'div'.  If the id is actually "div" then yeah use #div.