# How to select all child elements which are too deep in dom

Tags: css

I have html document like this:

```
<div id="obselect">
        <div id="objects">
          <span id="j_id0:j_id2:userPanel">
                    <table>
                       <tbody><tr>
                            <th class="subheading" width="40%">Available Objects</th>
                            <th class="subheading" width="20%">&nbsp;</th>
                            <th class="subheading" width="40%">Selected Objects</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span id="j_id0:j_id2:snondrag">
                                              <select name="j_id0:j_id2:j_id18" multiple="multiple" size="5">                             <option value="001">Account</option>
                                                  <option value="002">Note</option> 
                                                  <option value="a0j">Text Ad</option>
                                             </select>
                                  </span></td>

                            </tr>
                       </tbody>
                   </table>
        </span>
           </div>
</div>
```

In above code I need to apply css on `select` tag. But I am not able to find a way to to this. On my server this document is dynamically generated so i don't have control over which tags it uses. The only hardcoded `div` is outer most div :  `<div id="obselect">`. Is there any way to  apply style on all `select` tags inside this `div` by using something like:

```
#obselect > select
{
   // CSS
}
```

Comment: just use `#obselect  select`....and try

Comment: Yes that worked thanks for help. I was just confused between `>` and `<space> `.

Comment: well > will just select the direct child...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085688/selecting-a-specific-element-in-css/15085787#15085787

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use

```css
div#obselect select {
    ...
}
```

then the given style is applied to all elements of `select` inside any `div` with id '*obselect*', *regardless how deep it occurs in the DOM*.

(Notice that the selector `>` is especially meant for selecting only direct children.)

Answer (score 9):

The way to do it is use:

```
#obselect select
{
   // CSS
}
```

not:

```
#obselect > select
{
   // CSS
}
```

This is because the second one targets the direct children of the element with select not all of them

Answer (score 1):

You can leave out the `>` selector as that means you only want it to apply to direct descendants:

```
#obselect select
{
   // Targets all select elements under #obselect
}
```